# jQuery - Функция throttle на поле поиска

Tags: javascript, jquery

Никак не могу разобраться с функцией `throttle`. Подскажите, кто разбирается.

2-e ситуации, на которые нужно повесить задержку `throttle`, которое вешается на поле поиска:

1. Кликаем на кнопку поиска - появляется инпут (ранее был скрыт классом `hidden` по клику класс снимается, если класса не было уже - значит запускаем функцию поиска:

   ```
   if( $('.inputSearch').hasClass('hidden') )
       $('.inputSearch').removeClass('hidden').end().find('.inputSearch').focus();
   else{
       startSearch($('.inputSearch')); //startSearch - функция поиска
   }
   ```
2. Если в инпуте нажали `Enter`:

   ```
   $('.inputSearch').on('keydown', function(e){
       if (e.keyCode == 13){
           startSearch($('.inputSearch'))
   }
   ```

Пытался вешать кучу разных конструкций:

```
$.throttle(1000, startSearch(parent.find('.inputSearch')))
```

Ничего не работает у меня, пишет: `$.throttle is not a function`.

P.S. говорят, нужно именно с `throttle`, без `setTimeout` или `delay`.

Comment: Ты плагин не подключил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По ошибке видно, что проблема в нахождении функции.

А сам плагин `throttle-debounce` подключается? после подключения `jQuery`есть подобное?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: аааа, блин, я думал это без плагина работает, спасибо, видимо вот в чём проблема